# ADFS - On premises SSO Implementation

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, forms-authentication, adfs

I have an Asp.Net application that communicate with ADFS(on some other Windows Server) for authentication purpose. Currently, when we navigate to application, it redirects to ADFS SSO authentication page. I followed [this](http://goodworkaround.com/node/68) blog to implement SSO and have some questions here:

1. Can we change implementation so that it may redirect to authentication page only when I press login button ?
2. Can we change implementation so that only one page/URL of my application can be accessed without any authentication ?
3. What parameters are returned when user is authenticated and redirected back to landing page. How do we get all available parameters ? 
   In this [blog](http://goodworkaround.com/node/68) returning things are are Value, ValueType, Subject Name, Claim Issuer and Claim Issuer type. Can I get email or username ? so that I may link that person to a client in my application.

If anyone of above is possible, how I can get it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The login button is part of the ADFS screen. That's by design. The sample uses WIF so you are outsourcing authentication to ADFS.
2. Yes - Use the "location" annotation in the web.config. refer [Location Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).
3. The parameters that are returned are the claims configured in the claims rules. The article show "Display-Name" and UPN. If you want email, just add another row and select it from the dropdown.

Comment: nzpcmad, By point 1, I meant a scenario when we enter URL, instead of directly navigating to authentication page first, it should go to landing page first. What I want is, I only redirect to authentication page when I want.

Comment: Yup - just make your landing page unprotected. Then when ready redirect to any protected page and the auth. process will kick in.